# Remove Etags from Amazon S3 files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, etag

Is it a good idea to remove Etags from Amazon S3 files. I normal do this for regular files but I am just now stepping into the cdn world. Not sure if they need these to keep them updated or what?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove the Etags on S3 files.

Amazon creates these automatically for any uploaded files and they cannot be changed or removed.

Comment: I have files that I know will never ever change. Therefore, I'd like there to be zero network requests checking etags on second attempts to get a file. Can we do this?